# How to pipe mdfind to grep with a pattern and then cp

Tags: macos, terminal, spotlight

I have been trying to come up with a mdfind to locate certain files. I am not using find because it takes too long to search across a windows drive and I am on a Mac. I have indexed using mdutil and now simply want to search for files with the pattern where the file in the path starts with example. "/Volumes/DRIVE/SOME/PATH/**DAD14**-BLAH-BLAH.jpg". There must be a simpler way to use mdfind to look for a jpg greater than 500k and grep the path with a pattern? Below is the code I have come up with but no results are returned. Any help is deeply appreciated.

```
cat filelist.txt | while read -r FILE; 
   do mdfind -onlyin /Volumes/DRIVE/ 'kMDItemKind = "*image" && kMDItemFSSize > 500000' -name "$FILE" -0 
   | xargs -0 -I{} grep -i -E '.*\/[a-zA-Z]{1,3}[0-9]+.*\.(jpe?g|png|tiff?|psd)' {} 
   | xargs -0 -I{} cp -a {} ./images; done;
```

Bass

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use `xargs` for the `grep` command. Doing so means grepping the **contents** of the found files for matches of the pattern. You want to actually grep the output of `mdfind`.

That also means you don't want to use `-0` with `mdfind`. You want each file path to be on a separate line, since grep is going to output the matching lines. Therefore, you don't want to use `-0` with the final `xargs` command, either.

You probably want to require that the extension is at the end of the string. And you want the explicit slash (`/`) in your pattern to be the last slash in the string.

```
cat filelist.txt | while read -r FILE; 
   do mdfind -onlyin /Volumes/DRIVE/ 'kMDItemKind = "*image" && kMDItemFSSize > 500000' -name "$FILE" 
   | grep -i -E '.*\/[a-zA-Z]{1,3}[0-9]+[^/]*\.(jpe?g|png|tiff?|psd)$' 
   | xargs -I{} cp -a {} ./images; done;
```

Comment: Thank you for that swift response, I tried that but keep getting the following error: **xargs: insufficient space for argument**

Comment: Could it be that there are spaces in the filename hence why I was originally using the -0 option ?

Comment: Oops, I neglected to remove the `-0` from the remaining `xargs`. I've fixed it.

Comment: Thank you for that! I think the problem however may lie in the **'kMDItemKind = "*image" && kMDItemFSSize > 500000'** section and have no idea why mdfind doens't like these attributes?

Comment: Now I am getting a **xargs: unterminated quote** error ?